# ProGuard Cannot Find Referenced Libraries

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, proguard

```
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Note: there were 662 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Warning: there were 95 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-07-15 23:57:43 - MozMeet] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

This is the list of errors that I get when I try to export my Android app with `ProGuard` enabled. A little bit of Googling and I found that I need to add jar files to the `proguard-project.txt`. So far what I have added  looks like this (but to no avail):

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-libraryjars \libs\Parse-1.5.1.jar
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

I also have 3 more libraries along with Parse namely Crashlytics, Picasso and V4 Support.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Made a few changes to `proguard-project.txt` file (if you have more than one module in your project - put it in the module which calls the *.jar file you are getting warned about):

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

The `-dontwarn` lines were needed. Basically what they tell `ProGuard` is that these jars work fine on their own so don't complain when you cannot find the classes they reference.

Comment: The `-dontwarn` options indeed tell ProGuard to suppress the warnings and proceed. You should not add `-libraryjars` to your configuration. The Android build process (Ant, Eclipse, Gradle) already specifies those options for you.

Comment: In my case of building apk with picasso, `-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**` is needed for `proguard.flags`.

Comment: in my case the problem was exactly in using that common   proguard-project.txt instead of in-project  proguard-rules.pro oneA.ndroid Studio inspects your simple mistakes. E.g. I put  a space between '- 'and keep , or between  dot and asterisks.