# Parse SDK Android Proguard issue

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard

I have parse 1.5.1 in my app and everything works fine, but when I go to export to APK I get:

```
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Note: there were 662 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
......
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-09-05 19:53:08 - myapp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

In my proguard.cfg I have the following:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.parse.* { *; } 
-libraryjars libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar
```

This is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

You should try also keeping the subpackages of com.parse:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

You should not add `-libraryjars` options, since the Android build process already automatically specifies all necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you. It only causes warnings about duplicate classes.

Answer (score 4):

Mine was fixed by adding this:

```
-keep class com.parse.* { *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
```

Reference: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765588/proguard-cannot-find-referenced-libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the reference also.