# Android: Proguard is messing with me

Tags: android, proguard

I came here because I have spent hours on fixing my problem with proguard.

I can generate my debug-apk without any errors, while with proguard it has so many errors.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

now with these settings, I get the following errors:
(proguard-rules.pro = empty)

> Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced
>   class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient

so I added this line to my proguard-rules.pro: (according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24765921/6510329)

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
```

now I encounter the following error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write
 [C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\Spaarkaart5\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] 
(Can't read [C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.picasso\picasso\2.5.2\7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387\picasso-2.5.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [com/a/a/a$a.class == picasso-2.5.2.jar:com/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference.class]))
```

And the only place where picasso.jar is placed is in my root\app\libs

So I add this line to build.gradle because I know for sure this is the only place?

```
-injars libs\picasso-2.5.2.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\Spaarkaart5\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar]
 (Can't read [C:\Users\lexha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.picasso\picasso\2.5.2\7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387\picasso-2.5.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
 (Duplicate zip entry [com/a/a/a$a.class == picasso-2.5.2.jar:com/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference.class]))
```

which was the error I got before. Now I'm really confused, and I really don't know what to do right now.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your app build.gradle has `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your proguard

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames

#########--------Android Support--------#########
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.**

#########--------Picasso Setting--------#########    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a **`duplicate`** picasso library dependency in your app. Remove the jar in your `root\app\libs` and keep or add the picasso library in dependencies with:

```
dependencies {
  ..
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  ..
}
```